# Can I create an oracle ODBC driver without installing the Oracle Client?

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc, microsoft-access

recently I got a task to migrate the back end of an access database to oracle (the front end should still remain in access), I need an odbc connection for that and on the PC I am working on I don't have any administrative privilages. Whenever I am trying to add an Oracle ODBC driver an error message appears stating that I need an Oracle(tm) Client + some network ingredients first. The ODBC I am choosing from the list of currently available is : Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.

Is there any way to make it work without installing any client (that probably needs to save stuff in the registry which will lead to permission being denied)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [oracle instant client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html).  You just need to unzip and if you want to use tnsnames.ora set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable.